# Couchbase module cannot be found in Android studio

Tags: java, android, couchbase

I'm trying to build a project using couchbase. The thing is, the system cannot even locate the package. Thus when I try

```
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
// or any other of the below

import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;

import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument;
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject;
```

it says couchbase can't be located.

In build.gradle file I've tried including (among other different) these lines

```
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-ee:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.0.0'
// To access the database through HTTP (often used for hybrid development and peer-to-peer sync).
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-java-listener:1.4.4'
// To use ForestDB as the storage type.
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-forestdb:1.4.4'
// To enable encryption on SQLite databases.
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android-sqlcipher:1.4.4'
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-java-javascript:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.1.0'
```

I found these on stackoverflow. However, it seems that they no longer work / deprecated. I wonder if there is still a way to implement couchbase?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Couchbase Server or are you trying to embed Couchbase Lite in a Java app?

Comment: If you're using Server, what version are you using?

Comment: It's CouchbaseLite for now

Comment: I'm no Java developer, FYI, but I'm a little confused. You're importing `com.couchbase.client.java.*` but your bundle file is referencing `com.couchbase.lite...`. So I think you're trying to import the Server SDK libraries, but you actually want the Couchbase Lite SDK libraries. Have you gone through the Install docs for Couchbase Lite for Java? https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/java/gs-install.html